# How to connect a JQuery UI slider & a Web Audio API gainNode

Tags: web-audio-api

I am trying to connect a JQuery slider to a gain node of an oscillator using the Web Audio API.

The oscillator works, there is a working gain slider and there is a JQuery slider. I want the JQuery slider to control the gain like the other slider does.

Here is the code thus far

http://jsfiddle.net/taoist/JCTJj/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/JCTJj/19/

```
$(function() {
    var webSlider = document.getElementById('volume');
    var output = $('#gain');
    var sliderParams = {
        'orientation': "vertical",
        'range': "min",
        'min': 0,
        'max': 1,
        'animate': false,
        'step': 0.01,
        'slide': function(event, ui) {  
            window.gainNode.gain.value = ui.value;
            output.val(window.gainNode.gain.value);
        },
        'stop': function(event, ui) {
            console.log(window.gainNode.gain.value);
        }
    };

    $('#sliderOne').slider(sliderParams);
    webSlider.addEventListener('change', function () {
        window.gainNode.gain.value = this.value;
        output.val(window.gainNode.gain.value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

your gain function should recieve a value like

```
function gain(value) {

    gainNode.gain.value = value;
}
```

Then in jQuery slider do something like

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {

    gain(ui.value);                    
}
```